# Embeded MS Word in C# application

Tags: c#, winapi, ms-word, embed

I open a MS Word document in my program. Set parent for MS word one of panel

```
System.Diagnostics.Process pr = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessById(pid);
MainWindowHandleS = pr.MainWindowHandle;
SetParent(MainWindowHandleS, panel.Handle);
MoveWindow(MainWindowHandleS, 0, 0, panel.Width, panel.Height, false);
```

Problem with click on "File" on menu bar - MS Word open up on full area of my application, not only panel.
Can anyone help with some suggestions?

Comment: You'll want to give up on this idea. Using `SetParent` to make a window from one process be a child window in another process was something that was done in 16 bit Windows. That it can still be done today is purely a hangover from those days. You've got no hope of making this work well. Find a different solution.

Comment: As one potential approach to finding a different solution, does Word export any OLE objects?

Comment: You are right, but it must solved
So many legacy code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I problem solved(hack in mean).
By [Spy++](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/vstudio/dd460725.aspx)
search form created in File menu MS office app - with empty name, "FullPageUiHost" class. And with winapi repaint in new area.

```
IntPtr FileMenuHandle = (IntPtr)0;
private void Timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    IntPtr tmpHndl = FindWindowEx(MainForm.Handle, IntPtr.Zero, "FullPageUIHost", null);
    if (tmpHndl != IntPtr.Zero && FileMenuHandle == IntPtr.Zero)
    {
        FileMenuHandle = tmpHndl;
        SetParent(FileMenuHandle, Panel.Handle);
        MoveWindow(FileMenuHandle, 0, 0, Panel.Width, panel.Height, false);
    }
    else if (tmpHndl == IntPtr.Zero && FileMenuHandle != IntPtr.Zero)
        FileMenuHandle = IntPtr.Zero;
}
```